# Derivative of a polynomial in a maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and let $\mathfrak{m}\subset K[X]$ be a maximal ideal. Suppose that a polynomial $f(X)\in\mathfrak{m}$ has derivative $f'(X)\in\mathfrak{m}$. Then is it true that $f(X)\in\mathfrak{m}^2$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the claim to be true, a sufficient condition is$\;$char$(K)=0$.

Thus, suppose$\;$char$(K)=0$.

Let $m = (g)$, where $g$ is a non-constant, irreducible element of $K[x]$.

Since$\;$char$(K)=0,\;g\;$non-constant and irreducible in $K[x]$ implies $g$ relatively prime to $g'$, hence $g' \notin m$.

Suppose $f$ and $f'$ are both in $m$.

Let $f = gh$, where $h \in K[x]$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&f' \in m\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(gh)' \in m\\[4pt]
\implies\;&gh' + hg' \in m\\[4pt]
\implies\;&hg' \in m\\[4pt]
\implies\;&h \in m\;\;\text{or}\;\;g' \in m&&\text{[since $m$ is a prime ideal]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&h \in m&&\text{[since $g' \notin m$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&gh \in m^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f \in m^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.

However, if $K$ has nonzero characteristic, the argument above doesn't go through without some further restrictions on the field $K$.

The issue is that for the claim

$\qquad g$ non-constant, irreducible in $K[x]\implies g'$ is relatively prime to $g$

we need $g' \ne 0$.

In fact, if $g$ is a non-constant, irreducible element of $K[x]$, and $g'=0$, we can get a counterexample simply by choosing $f=g$.

In particular, here's a counterxample . . .

Let $p\;$be a prime, let $F_p$ be a finite field of order $p$, and let $K=F_p(t)$, where $t$ is an indeterminate.

Let $g \in K[x]$ be given by $g = x^p - t$, and let $m=(g)$.

Then $g\;$is a non-constant, irreducible element of $K[x]$, hence the ideal $m$ is maximal (since $K[x]$ is a PID).

But note that $g'=0$.

Then $g$ and $g'$ are both in $m$, but $g \notin m^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $K$ is a field, $K[X]$ is a principal ideal domain; thus. $\mathfrak m = (p(X))$ for some $p(X) \in K[X]$; since $\mathfrak m$ is maximal, $p(X)$ is irreducible;  since $K[X]$ is a principal ideal domain, $p(X)$ is also prime.  Now with $f(X) \in \mathfrak m$, we have

$f(X) = g(X)p(X) \tag 1$

for some $g(X) \in K[X]$; thus

$f'(X) = g'(X)p(X) + g(X)p'(X), \tag 2$

or

$f'(X) - g'(X)p(X) = g(X)p'(X); \tag 3$

since $f'(X) \in \mathfrak m$, we also have

$f'(X) = h(X) p(X) \tag 4$

for some $h(X) \in K[X]$; thus,

$h(X) p(X) - g'(X)p(X) = g(X) p'(X); \tag 5$

we see from (5) that $p(X) \mid g(X) p'(X)$; since $p(X)$ is prime, we have $p(X) \mid g(X)$ or $p(X) \mid p'(X)$; but $p(X) \not \mid p'
(X)$ since $\deg p'(X) < \deg p(X)$; thus $p(X) \mid g(X)$, whence $g(X) = q(X) p(X)$, whence

$f(X) = q(X)(p(X))^2 \in \mathfrak m^2. \tag 6$

***Note Added in Edit, Friday 8 September 2017 8:40 PM PST:***  The above answer suffers from the same foible as mentioned by quasi in the notes he added to his post.  Here it manifests itself as the assertion that $p(X) \not \mid p'(X)$, which is obviously false if $p'(X) = 0$; then we can't force $p(X) \mid g(X)$ by virtue of the fact that $p(X) \not \mid p'(X)$.  Evidently, this problem does not appear when $\operatorname{char} K \ne 0$.  ***End of Note.***